# Flex 4 - Using MXML as views - Any references?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm looking to create a flashBuilder document which uses seperate MXML files as "views" which are controlled by states - I believe it's a design pattern of sorts but I'm relatively new to FlashBuilder. I was wondering if anyone knew what design pattern it was and if I can be pointed in the direction of some good references!

FYI I'm looking into using FlashBuilder to design Android apps so any better suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You can look for Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control based on the MVC pattern. Search for a framework like Robotlegs,Swiz,Mate. I highly recommend Robotlegs

Answer (score 1):

You can do that the way you want. Just consider such file (MXML) as object. It can be easily added to some outer component, ie. UIComponent. You should read something about it but I bet it's quite simple. Just remember - MXML is just a language that describes an object - you could do that using AS 3.0 instead but it's obviously more convenient to use MXML. Considering this fact all the MXML files are compiled before they run so you can easily manipulate them.

Just try to add such object to some outer component like UIComponent - you can read a few words about it here: [HTML in Flex](http://flex-blogger.com/blog/2010/12/11/flex-and-html-embedded-in-iframe/). Just take a look at the function *createWindow*

Good luck!